# How does one sign cloudfront urls for files stored on s3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I will attempt to answer this question with the hope of helping others who come across the same concern. Also with the hope of someone pointing out what I am missing (if any) or improvements along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you will need is to create a key pair at https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials (`Key Pairs tab`). Which will provide you with a `key pair id` and a `pem file` (save the pem file in your project dir).

In your AWS Cloudfront portal, create a distribution. Select `yes` for `Restrict Bucket Access`.

Click `yes` for `Grant Read Permissions on Bucket`. This will add a bucket policy allowing your Cloudfront distribution to read files on your S3 bucket.

Create the distribution.

In your S3 bucket, have a file that is not public. i.e. no read permissions. In this case, we will test this against `test.png`.

```
url = "https://actual_cdn_id_here.cloudfront.net/test.png"
key_pair_id = 'your_aws_key_pair_id'
expires_in = 1.minute

expires = (Time.now.getutc + expires_in).to_i.to_s

private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read('private_key_file.pem'))

policy = %Q[{"Statement":[{"Resource":"#{url}","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":#{expires}}}}]}]
signature = Base64.strict_encode64(private_key.sign(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, policy))

"#{url}?Expires=#{expires}&Signature=#{signature}&Key-Pair-Id=#{key_pair_id}"
```

Hope this helps someone. If there is a need for improvement / suggestions for this solution, do mention.